# sql query related to codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

**View:::**

```html
                       <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Signup/profile">


                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Company Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="company_name" value="<?php echo  $det->company_name; ?>" required>
                        </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Upload Company Logo</label>
                            <input type="file" name="company_pic" accept="image/*" class="form-control" vlaue="<?php echo $det->company_pic; ?>" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Upload Profile Picture</label>
                   <input type="file" name="profile_pic" accept="image/*" class="form-control" vlaue="<?php echo $det->profile_pic; ?>" required>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Projects Done</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="projects_done" value="<?php echo $det->projects_done; ?>" required>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>No Of Employees</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="num_of_emp" value="<?php echo $det->num_of_emp; ?>"required>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Founding Year</label>
       </br>
       </br>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="found_year" value="<?php echo $det->found_year; ?>" required>
                        </div>

                        <div class="container">
                            <label>Service Offering</label></br>
        <?php
$new_array=array('1'=>'Engineering and Design','2'=>'Operations and support','3'=>'Product management','4'=>'Developer relations and technical solutions','5'=>'Sales and account management','6'=>'Partnerships','7'=>'Sales and operations','8'=>'Administrative services','9'=>'Business strategy planning','10'=>'Finance solutions','11'=>'Legal and government relations','12'=>'Marketing and communications','13'=>'Real estate and workplace services','14'=>'Social impact solutions','15'=>'Consultancy services','16'=>'Investors and funding');

  if(isset($new_array)) 
   $services = array_column($services,'service_offered');
         foreach($new_array as $key=>$val):

        if($db_key = array_search($val,$services))
         {  ?>
            <input type="checkbox" name='service[]'    value="<?php echo $key ?>" checked ><?php echo $val; ?> <br/>
       <?php  }
         else
         { 
?>
           <input type="checkbox" name='service[]'    value="<?php echo $key ?>" ><?php echo $val; ?><br/>
        <?php   }

 endforeach; ?>

       
                            
                        </div>
<br><br>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Locations</label>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name='locations' value="1" <?php if($det->locations==="Hyderabad")echo "checked";?>>Hyderabad
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name='locations' value="2" <?php if($det->locations==="Pune")echo "checked";?>>Pune
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name='locations' value="3" <?php if($det->locations==="Bangalore")echo "checked";?>>Banglore
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name='locations' value="4" <?php if($det->locations==="Delhi")echo "checked";?>>Delhi
                                </label>
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name='locations' value="5" <?php if($det->locations==="Kolkata")echo "checked";?>>Kolkata
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name='locations' value="6" <?php if($det->locations==="Chennai")echo "checked";?>>Chennai
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          <button type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
                           </form>
```

**Controller::**

```html
public function profile()
     {
  $vendor=$this->input->post();
  
  $service_id=$this->input->post('service');
  unset($vendor['service']);
  
     $loc_id=$this->input->post('locations');
     $login_email=$this->session->userdata('email_id');
  $vendor['locations']=$this->Vendormodel->get_location($loc_id);
  print_r($vendor); exit;
     $this->Vendormodel->add_vendor_profile($login_email,$vendor);
  $id1=$this->Vendormodel->get_vendor_id($login_email);
   if(isset($service_id))
  foreach($service_id as $id){
  $post[]=$this->Vendormodel->get_services($id);
  }
  if(isset($service_id))
  foreach($post as $service){
  $this->Vendormodel->add_vendor_services($id1,$service);
  }
  
  $vendordash['det']=$this->Vendormodel->vendor_details($login_email);
  $vendordash['services']=$this->Vendormodel->vendor_services($id1);
  
  $this->load->view('vendor/vendor_dashboard',$vendordash);
 
  }
```

**Model::**

```html
public function add_vendor_services($id,$service)
  {
   $query = $this->db->get('vendor_services');

            foreach ($query->result() as $row)
            {
             $ids[]=$row->id;
    
            }
   if(isset($ids)){
           foreach($ids as $vid){
   if($id==$vid){
    $q1 =$this->db->get_where('vendor_services',array('id'=>$vid));
    $serv=$q1->row()->service_offered;
    if($serv===$service)
     return;
    else{
  $this->db->set('id',$id)
           ->set('service_offered',$service)
           ->insert('vendor_services');
   return;
   }}else{$this->db->set('id',$id)
           ->set('service_offered',$service)
           ->insert('vendor_services');
     return;
     }
   }}
  else
   {$this->db->set('id',$id)
           ->set('service_offered',$service)
           ->insert('vendor_services');
     return;
     }
   
  
  }
```

I have a table in database with table name: vendor_services. It contains 'id' and 'service_offered'. I am trying to fetch vendor id and service from form where service is in array, and put it in vendor_services table. But I don't want to insert a service for a specific vendor id which already exists.

Suppose service1 for vendor 1 is already present in table if service1 appears again for vendor id 1, it should not be inserted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no unique key on vendor_services(id, service_offered) then you will need to manually check the combination yourself first then decide where to insert or not.  This should work for that situation:

```
public function add_vendor_services($id,$service) {
            $this->db->select('*')->from('vendor_services')
                ->where('id',$id)
                ->where('service_offered',$service);

            if($this->db->get()->num_rows() > 0){
                // already have this service for this vendor
            } else {
                // need to add this service to this vendor
                $this->db->insert('vendor_services',array('id'=>$id,'service_offered'=>$service));
            }
}
```

If there is a unique key on the id & service_offered columns then you could just do this:

```
public function add_vendor_services($id,$service) {
    $this->db->replace('vendor_services',array('id'=>$id,'service_offered'=>$service));
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy its working!!